# Any update for CMake enabled?

Tags: cmake, bazel

The [road-map](https://bazel.build/roadmaps/external-deps.html#2018-q3) of bazel said it would support CMake on 2018.Q3, any update for it?

Thanks.

Added: the roadmap link: https://bazel.build/roadmaps/external-deps.html#2018-q3

Answer (score 3):

[`rules_foreign_cc`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc) has experimental CMake integration.

Example from the [README](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc#building-cmake-projects):

```
cmake_external(
   name = "eigen",
   # These options help CMake to find prebuilt OpenBLAS, which will be copied into
   # $EXT_BUILD_DEPS/openblas by the cmake_external script
   cache_entries = {
       "BLA_VENDOR": "OpenBLAS",
       "BLAS_LIBRARIES": "$EXT_BUILD_DEPS/openblas/lib/libopenblas.a",
   },
   headers_only = True,
   lib_source = "@eigen//:all",
   # Dependency on other cmake_external rule; can also depend on cc_import, cc_library rules
   deps = [":openblas"],
)
```